# Entity Framework Customize EDM Generation For FK Relation Names

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I am happily using entity framework with WPF and C# under VS 2010. After generating the EDM using the default generator i need to manually modify some of the foreign key relations as the default generated are not satisfactory. Although i saw that it is possible, i was not able to find a quick way to customize the foreign key relation names specifically. Could some one spare some short but worthy example of how to achieve that ?

Many Thanks...

Comment: What do you mean by example? You will simply open EDMX file in the designer select navigation property or relation you want to rename and type a new name in the properties window.

Comment: I mean that i want to AUTO generate my special names and not manually change all FK names each time i recreate the EDM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify the process used to generate entities and names when using EDM generator (adding tables to the designer via wizard). That is one of reasons why you have the designer - it allows you easily modifying all names you need. You usually need to change names only once because the designer will not touch your changes when updating the model from the database (if you delete entities and add them again then you of course have to) but there are some situation when EDM Designer behaves strangely and revert names of some relations back to default values but it doesn't happen for properties which are more important.

Comment: Try it, you will see it yourselves. That doesn't modify behaviour of the import wizard. That only allows you creating classes and context from the EDMX = it uses names specified in the EDMX. If you don't change them in EDMX you will get the same wrong names in entities as now.